# В какой архив можно собрать файлы, чтобы сохранить их разрешения?

Tags: архивация

То есть, собрал много файлов с разными разрешениями в архив. Мне необходимо собрать в такой архив, после распаковки, которого все содержащиеся в нем файлы, будут распакованы с такими же разрешениями. На пример: собрал в архив файл с разрешением 777, и что бы после распаковки этого архива файл так и остался с разрешением 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многие современные архиваторы сохраняют полную информацию о файлах и директориях, в том числе имя, расширение (это просто часть имени), время создания, атрибуты и пр.

Из бесплатных большой популярностью пользуется [tar](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar). Но этот архиватор не сжимает файлы и поэтому используется в связке с другими архиваторами - gzip, xz, zip и пр.